# Best way to save data using Socket IO

Tags: socket.io

I'm learning how to use Socket.IO, and I'm building a small game.

When someone creates a room, I save the room values in a array.

```
var clients = [], rooms = [];
...
rooms.push(JSON.parse(roomData));
```

But if the server crashes, the server loses all the rooms Data.

Is it a good idea to save the data into a Database and repopulate the array with these values when the user connects to the server?

Thank you.

Comment: Restoring socket.io connection state after a server crash is a complicated topic.  State can be stored to disk, to another in memory process like redis or in the client and presented when they reconnect,  You just have to devise how everything gets restored when the server restarts and the clients reconnect.  There are multiple ways to do it.  So, yes you could use a DB or you could do it a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restoring socket.io connection state after a server crash is a complicated topic that depends a lot on exactly what you're doing and what the state is.  Sometimes the client can hold most of the state, sometimes it must be persisted on the server.

State can be stored to disk, to another in memory process like redis or in the client and presented when they reconnect.

You just have to devise a sequence of events on your server and then when the client reconnects for how everything gets restored.  You will also likely need persistent client IDs so you know which client is which when they reconnect.

There are many different ways to do it. So, yes you could use a DB or you could do it a different way.  There is no single "best" way because it depends upon your particular circumstances and tools you are already using.